# Styling Preference.SwitchPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferencescreen

I'm trying to style my SwitchPreference elements in my PreferenceFragment.

What I did was defining a style

```
<style name="CustomSwitchPreference">
    <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/custom_switch</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/switch_background</item>
</style>
```

and then setting the style to my elements

```
    <SwitchPreference
        android:key="log_all_toast"
        android:width="10dip"
        android:height="7dip"
        android:switchTextOn="@string/yes"
        android:switchTextOff="@string/no"
        android:title="@string/settings_log_all_toast_title"
        android:summary="@string/settings_log_all_toast_summary"
        style="@style/CustomSwitchPreference"/>
```

The two drawables are selectors properly defined. I actually took inspiration for them from another post on stackoverflow.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/switch_disabled" />
<item android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/switch_pressed" />
<item android:state_checked="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/switch_active" />
<item                               android:drawable="@drawable/switch_default" />
```

and

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/switch_bg_disabled_holo_dark" />
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/switch_bg_focused_holo_dark" />
<item                               android:drawable="@drawable/switch_bg_holo_dark" />
```

What happens is... nothing. No errors, but also no styling.

Did you ever manage to style your own SwitchPreference? I couldn't find much about it online.

Thank you